# Как сделать данный слайдер адаптивным?

Tags: javascript

Мучаюсь уже третий день с вот этим слайдером:

http://koftastudio.com/test/test/index.html

Проблема заключается в том что весь этот слайдер написан под px а не под % через файл js

вот кстати он [ссылка](http://koftastudio.com/test/test/scripts/jquery.carousel-1.1.min.js)

а мне нужно его подогнать как под обычные компьютеры так и под очень большое разрешение mac 5120х2880 пикселей(там слайдер выходит совсем крошечный).
И я столкнулся с проблемой, не могу найти код(не хватает знаний) отвечающий именно за изменение конфигурации px на % самих изображений.Всего слайдера нашел, но это особо не помогает.
По умолчанию я выставил центральную фотографию слайда 1000px на 670px и в зависимости от перелистывания пропорции размеров изменяются.Нужно заменить именно вместо 1000px - 100% и чтоб в пропорциях оно тоже было в процентах.

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83)